# Why can't my GetManifestResourceStream find my image?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap

I'm currently attempting to layer several images into a single composite, built from several body face pieces for a player's portrait.

Usually for grabbing images from the resources and putting them into a picturebox/etc I'd simply ".Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(filename)".

However I need to transfer to a Bitmap, which doesn't accept objects. I've found the below code from a couple of google results, but the file is bugging out as "Value of null is not valid for 'stream' ", and the pHead is "Nothing". As such I'm presuming the code can't find the file.

The break is causing on the final line of the below code.

Any help or simpler alternatives would be much welcome.

```
 Dim GenderText As String = ""
 Select Case ListCharacter(ActiveChar).Gender
     Case eGender.Male : GenderText = "masc"
     Case eGender.Female : GenderText = "fem"
 End Select

 Dim Prefix As String = ""
 Dim Suffix As String = ".png"
 Dim myAsm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

' Load Head Image
' e.g. prt_fem_head_1_white.png
 Dim headImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_head_" & CharApp.HeadStyle & "_" & CharApp.SkinColour
 Dim pHead As Bitmap = New Bitmap(myAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(Me.GetType, headImageName & Suffix))
```

[image: Screenshot]

ps. Also bugs out with/without the suffix.

Edit #1;

I've found the prefix required, as far as I can tell, to the whereabouts of the resources root. However, that still isn't working to any variation.
[image: Screenshot2]

Edit #2;

I've double checked the resource location via its properties.

"C:\Users\CLEO\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Storytime\Storytime\Resources\prt_fem_head_1_white.png"

Comment: I've tried breaking down the code more accurately to a pre-existing image I have used elsewhere as an object. I've tried the folliowing;
- Storytime.Resources.Hoof.png :::
- Storytime.Resources.Hoof :::
- Resources.Hoof.png :::
- Resource.Hoof :::
- Hoof :::
- Hoof.png :::

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong.  You would have to use ResourceReader to decode the manifest resource stream and dig out the bitmap out of the stream.  That still gets you the exact same object that  ResourceManager.GetObject() provides so you are completely not head.  Very hard to guess what "doesn't accept objects" could possibly mean, you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I changed the code out for a simpler one I found in my Resources Designer code. The below is very raw and needs tidying, but this is how I was able to make several images build into one picturebox.

```
' Load Face
    Dim PortraitLocation As New Point(573, 51)
    Dim CharApp As New Character.cAppearance : CharApp = ListCharacter(ActiveChar).Appearance
    '   Dim pHead, pEyes, pNose, pMouth, pBase, pHair As New PictureBox
    Dim FaceCanvas As New PictureBox

    Dim GenderText As String = ""
    Select Case ListCharacter(ActiveChar).Gender
        Case eGender.Male : GenderText = "masc"
        Case eGender.Female : GenderText = "fem"
    End Select

    Dim resourceCulture As Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo

    Dim headImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_head_" & CharApp.HeadStyle & "_" & CharApp.SkinColour
    Dim obj As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(headImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim phead As Bitmap = CType(obj, System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Dim eyesImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_eyes_" & CharApp.EyeStyle & "_" & CharApp.SkinColour
    Dim obj2 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(eyesImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim pEyes As Bitmap = CType(obj2, System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Dim noseImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_nose_" & CharApp.NoseStyle & "_" & CharApp.SkinColour
    Dim obj3 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(noseImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim pNose As Bitmap = CType(obj3, System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Dim mouthImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_mouth_" & CharApp.MouthStyle & "_" & CharApp.SkinColour
    Dim obj4 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(mouthImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim pMouth As Bitmap = CType(obj4, System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Dim hairImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_hair_" & CharApp.HairStyle & "_" & CharApp.HairColour
    Dim obj5 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(hairImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim pHair As Bitmap = CType(obj5, System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Dim bodyImageName As String = "prt_" & GenderText & "_body_" & CharApp.SkinColour
    Dim obj6 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(bodyImageName, resourceCulture)
    Dim pBody As Bitmap = CType(obj6, System.Drawing.Bitmap)


    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pBody)
    g.DrawImage(phead, 0, 0)
    g.DrawImage(pEyes, 0, 0)
    g.DrawImage(pNose, 0, 0)
    g.DrawImage(pMouth, 0, 0)
    g.DrawImage(pHair, 0, 0)
    With FaceCanvas
        .Location = PortraitLocation
        .Size = New Size(50, 50)
        .Image = pBody
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(FaceCanvas)
```

[image: pic0]
[image: pic1]